# How to have both HTTP and TCP server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, tcp

I intend to deploy a nodejs app on Heroku which is both an HTTP and TCP server. I can see that I can map my application to a routed port using process.env.PORT. However, this would be just one port, yes? I couldn't map both my HTTP server and TCP server to the same port. Is there a way that I can do this, possibly by getting a second routed port?

Please note, my TCP client applications are not necessarily going to be nodejs (probably Python), so I need something lower level than `socket.io` and `websockets`. I was going to use `net`.

Answer (score 0):

**TCP and HTTP are in different layers.**

- HTTP is under the Application Layer.
- TCP is under the Transportation Layer.

An HTTP client initiates a request by establishing a Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) connection to a particular port on a server (typically port 80).

In computer networks, every application is getting/asking from the operating system a port that it can listen to.

If you have 2  **TCP servers**- one is HTTP server and the other one is another server,  **they can't listen to the same port**, unless you have two NI because of the TCP protocol operations.

Comment: I am aware that they can't listen on the same port. I said so in my question (first paragraph, 4th sentence). I am asking how to get a second routed port on Heroku, or what some other workaround might be.